# Как исправить код sqlite?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

```
cur.execute(f"""UPDATE profiles 
                SET priority = '{priority}' 
                FROM profiles INNER JOIN priorities ON profiles.priority = priorities.name 
                WHERE priorities.rowid IN({", ".join(rows)})""")
```

`rows` список строк, `priority` - строка, но команда не работает.

Error:

```
target object/alias may not appear in FROM clause: profiles
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А если вывести на печать получившуюся в аргументе функции строку, посмотреть, что там. Подозреваю, что `rows` должны быть в кавычках каждая, чтобы команда сработал

Comment: @CrazyElf прога крашеется.

Comment: Значит у вас есть ошибка. Прикрепите её к вопросу. И лучше в виде текста.

Comment: А вообще я имел в виду вместо `cur.execute` сделайте `print`, чтобы посмотреть какая строка сформировалась

Comment: А, ну так у вас там написано, что вы не можете при обновлении данных в таблице использовать FROM с той же таблицей. У вас ошибка в SQL запросе, питон тут вообще не при чём.

Comment: @CrazyElf так какую мне таблицу там указать?

Comment: Почитайте ответы на этот вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270259/update-with-join-in-sqlite